# Get multiple MAX values from single query across multiple columns using Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to select the max values of 3 columns from a table.  All the fields being returned from the query are Strings.

What I have sofar

```
var step1 =  from result in t_hsbc_staging_trts_derived_tbl_ac_balance.AsQueryable()
             where result.branch_no == brnchnu
                && result.deal_id == dealid
                && result.group_mbr == grpmem
                && result.ac_type != "RMC"
             select result ;

var branch = from result in step1
             select new {ccbranch = result.cc_branch.Max()};
var sect = from result in step1
           select new { ccsect = result.cc_sect.Max()};
var dept = from result in step1
             select new { ccdept = result.cc_dept.Max()};

foreach (var result in branch)
{
  string cc_branch = result.ccbranch.ToString();
}
```

The error I'm getting at the foreach statement is:

> Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'.

There must be an easier way to just get the max values from this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `Max()` function on `result.cc_branch` which is itself a string. Even if it was successful, it would return the character of the string that has the largest unicode number, i.e.

```
 string s = "one-two-three";
 Console.WriteLine(s.Max()); // returns 'w'
```

Since I assume that is not what you want, and that you want the largest branch / section / department value, you can use:

```
string branch = (from result in step1 select result.cc_branch).Max();
string sect = (from result in step1 select result.cc_sect).Max();
string dept = (from result in step1 select result.cc_dept).Max();
```

Comment: How do you know  result.cc_branch is string ? its no where mentioned.

Comment: @Saurabh: It's mentioned in the question by the OP, and also the error is very suggestive.

Comment: With method syntax it will be even better `step1.Max(r => r.cc_branch)`